# Vectorized matrix and array multiplication in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, vectorization, multiplication

I could not figure out, how to write a vectorized version of the following matrix and array multiplication:

```
v = rep(0.1, 2)
v2 = matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
A = matrix(0.25, nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
R = matrix(- 1, nrow = 2, ncol = 3)  
P = array(1:12, dim = c(2, 2, 3))
for (i in 1:3) {
  v2[, i] = A[, i] * (R[, i] + P[, , i] %*%  v)
}
v = rowSums(v2)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: I think we have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) over here. I could help you vectorize this exact code, however, I think that I could give an even more efficient solution if you would tell me what your actual goal is.

Comment: You're right, I'm actually looking for a more efficient way to compute the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that we are faced with is that we want to do matrix multiplication over `P`, a 3d `array`. As this is not efficiently possible, it is better to transform this `array` to a 2d column `matrix`.

```
P <- array(1:12, dim = c(2, 2, 3))
P <- matrix(P, nrow = 2)
```

The `A` and `R` matrices don't have to be adjusted for this to work

```
A <- matrix(0.25, nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
R <- matrix(-1, nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
```

Matrix multiplication with the `v` vector can then be accomplished by transforming the column vector into a sparse block diagonal matrix with the `bdiag(...)` function from the `Matrix` package.

```
library(Matrix)

v <- rep(0.1, 2)
v <- bdiag(v, v, v)

## [1,] 0.1 .   .  
## [2,] 0.1 .   .  
## [3,] .   0.1 .  
## [4,] .   0.1 .  
## [5,] .   .   0.1
## [6,] .   .   0.1
```

This gives the same result as before, however, this time in a vectorized manner.

```
v <- rowSums(A * (R + (P %*% v)))
## [1] 0.15 0.30
```

**Edit:** In the above equation I use two types of multiplication: `*`, the dot-product, which computes the element-wise products between two matrices of equal size, and `%*%`, the ordinary matrix product, which computes the matrix product of two conformable matrices, or in other words, the number of columns of the first, and the number of rows of the second matrix should be equal.

**Edit2:** As requested I have included how to transform the given `P` `array` to a `matrix`.

**Edit3:** This method can be generalized by introducing a variable `n` for the number of groups. The key adjustment is in the declaration of the block diagonal matrix, as next to individual matrices, this function also takes a list of matrices as input. This results in the following solution

```
library(Matrix)
n <- 3
P <- array(1:12, dim = c(2, 2, n))
P <- matrix(P, nrow = 2)
A <- matrix(0.25, nrow = 2, ncol = n)
R <- matrix(-1, nrow = 2, ncol = n) 
v <- rep(0.1, 2)
v <- bdiag(rep(list(v),n))
v <- rowSums(A * (R + (P %*% v)))
## [1] 0.15 0.30
```

Comment: Thanks that helps :) Can you add the code how to transform the given array P to a matrix?

Comment: This would be `matrix(P, nrow = 2, ncol = 6)`

Comment: How to change the code when the number of columns in `A` and `R` and array dimension in `P` is dependent on a variable parameter `n`, so for example for `n=4` it works with `v <- bdiag(v, v, v, v)`, but for `n=2` it works with `v <- bdiag(v, v)`. How to change the code so that it works for every `n`?

Comment: See my edit above. Rewriting code from specific to general is a very useful skill. The next time I would recommend you to try it yourself, post your progress, and then ask for additional help.